# Why does webpack not work offline without internet connection

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack for my React projects local development. When I run `npm start` it throws this error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: addMembership ENODEV
```

But when I go online the error is gone and it works fine.

Any help is appreciated because I will be working offline for a long time.

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: did you download node.js package and use it locally?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because webpack-dev-server uses bonjour even if it is not needed. here is discussion: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/979

Comment: Also seems the fix has already been done, so only need to wait for the next patch release: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/958